# XML parser (Unmarshall) using JaxB to get elemet from xml file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

I new to jaxB XML parser. i need to get the all the attribute (idref, type, name, scope) from element tag ** I tried something but getting error.

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
    <xmi:XMIxmi:version="2.1"xmlns:uml="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901"xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1" xmlns:thecustomprofile="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/thecustomprofile/1.0" xmlns:SysML="http://www.omg.org/spec/SysML/20161101/SysML">
        <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5" exporterID="1555"/>
            <xmi:Extension extender="Enterprise Architect" extenderID="6.5">
                <elements>
      <element xmi:idref="EAPK_5560E5AF_736A_4703_AC79_CA3FAA60984B" xmi:type="uml:Package" name="PackageView" scope="public"></element>
                    <element xmi:idref="EAPK_59058493_9220_4b05_888A_67C6854C97EC" xmi:type="uml:Package" name="Read from Communication Interface" scope="public">  
                    </element>
                    <element xmi:idref="EAID_870B8E54_0FF2_4a90_A9C1_23F477DF695F" xmi:type="uml:Activity" name="Read from communication interface" scope="public">
                    </element>
                </elements>
            </xmi:Extension>
        </xmi:XMI>
```

**Main Class**

```
public class XmlElement {
        
          public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            JAXBContext jaxbContext;
            String fileLocation = "C:\\vinoth\\XML_JaxbParser\\elements.xml";
            try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileLocation)) {
                System.out.println("******** PARSING START ********");
                jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Xmi.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                elements elements = (elements) unmarshaller.unmarshal(fileInputStream);
                System.out.println(elements);
                System.out.println("******** PARSING DONE ********");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("******** ERROR: SOMETHING WENT WRONG ********");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
```

**elements.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "xmi")
    
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    
        public class Elements {
         @XmlElement(name = "elements")
          private List<Elements> elements;
          // Generate Getters and Setters...
          @Override
          public String toString() {
            return "Elements [elements="+ elements +"]";
          }
        }
```

**element.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        public class Element {
          @XmlAttribute(name = "idref")
          private String idref;
          @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
          private String type;
          @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
          private String name;
          @XmlAttribute(name = "scope")
          private String scope;
        //Generate Getters and Setters...
          @Override
          public String toString() {
            return "Element [idref=" + idref + ",type=" + type + ", name=" + name + ", scope=" + scope+ "]";
          }
        
        }
```

I need to get the the element attribute from the given XML file. I don't know where I made a mistake. Root element and parent and children, i can understand mistake from mapping section. but I couldn't sort out.

Comment: Errors are usually there to tell you what is wrong. Not including it in your question makes solving issues a lot harder for anyone else.

Comment: There are a few spaces missing in your XML between  element name and attributes. I don't know if this your real XML-code, or just an inaccurate copy&paste here.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML file uses many different [XML namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp),
which you need to consider in your Java code.

Especially notice, that the namespace *URIs* (e.g.
`"http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1"`) are the
only relevant thing. The namespace *prefixes* (e.g. `xmi:`) are not
relevant for Java. They were only invented to make the XML
easier to read for humans.

I recommend to define all your XML namespace URIs as Java
string contants to avoid typing them many times in your code:

```
public class NameSpaces {
    public final static String UML = "http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901";
    public final static String XMI = "http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1";
    public final static String THE_CUSTOM_PROFILE = "http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/thecustomprofile/1.0";
    public final static String SYSML = "http://www.omg.org/spec/SysML/20161101/SysML";
}
```

You need to carefully look at your XML content (XML elements
`XMI`, `Documentation`, `Extension`, `Elements`, `Element` and
their XML attributes) to see which XML namespace is used where.
Then in *all* your Java classes you need to specify the right
namespace in the `@XmlAttribute` and `@XmlElement` annotations.
You will also need to specify a namespace in the `@XmlRootElement`
annotation of your root class.
See also the [Javadoc of the JAXB annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html).

I will not do all your work for you, but instead only show how
your root class and the `Element` class may look like.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "XMI", namespace = NameSpaces.XMI)
public class XMI {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "version", namespace = NameSpaces.XMI)
    private String version;

    @XmlElement(name = "Documentation", namespace = NameSpaces.XMI)
    private Documentation documentation;

    @XmlElement(name = "Extension", namespace = NameSpaces.XMI)
    private Extension extension;

    // Getters, setters, toString omitted here for brevity
}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Element {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "idref", namespace = NameSpaces.XMI)
    private String idref;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "type", namespace = NameSpaces.XMI)
    private String type;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "scope")
    private String scope;

    // Getters, setters, toString omitted here for brevity
}
```